# Anylogic GIS realtime traffic data

Tags: gis, anylogic

I am wondering `Anylogic` has a function of adding real-time traffic data on a road,
currently `Anylogic` is able to bring up `GIS` data on their system.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot load real-time traffic data by default. AnyLogic only allows you to access what the selected map-provider (OSM) provides for free.

However, you can purchase access to that data from Google and/or Bing and access it via the "advanced" properties of your GIS map object (tick "use custom tile provider" and "use custom routes provider").